# Moment.js set the base time from the server

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have been reading the documentation, and cannot seem to find a method to set the date from the server as opposed to the client?

For example something like this

```
moment().set('server time')
```

Then **moment()** would return the Date Object based on server's time as opposed to the time from the client's computer.

Does this functionality exist, and if not what are some recommended methods you would use? Right now I am polling the server to get the server's time, but as you can imagine this is not very efficient.

### UPDATED WITH CODE EXAMPLE AND SUMMARY

I am building an auction application. So server time is critical. For example if the user has tampered with their time settings or their time has been manually configured, the client might see an auction that has already ended, when in fact it still has a few minutes left. All time checks are obviously done on the server, but that is why  I need the client and server to be in sync. Now you can see I am polling the server to get the latest time every few seconds. However what I need is to set moment() to call the base time from the variable I pass from the server. So everytime I call moment() it bases the time from the time passed in initially instead of new Date().

```
app.getTime = ->
    setInterval ->
        $.get app.apiUrl + 'public/time', (time)  -> 
            app.now = moment(time).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')
    , app.fetchTimeInterval
```

Somewhere else in my application I use the app's server time like so

```
collection = new Auction.DealershipBasket [], query: "?$orderby=Ends&$filter=Ends lt datetime'#{app.now}'"
```

Instead I would like to call the following and it returns the time from server which I only need to configure once with a get request from the url above.

```
 now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')
```

Comment: Does it have to be the exact servertime? Else I would recommend just using the timezone from the server to convert the local time. Since most clocks are synchronized via a timeserver the difference should be very small (unless someone of course has tampered with their time settings).

Comment: I would look at an approach of getting the servertime once and then storing the difference to the local time. Then you could wrap your call to moment with your own function that adjusts the time accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm. Very interesting Idea. I definitely think thats worth a try. Just thought Moment would let you specify a base time. Probably should look at the source and see how easy it would be to fork and add the functionality.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to ask the server once for the current time and then compute the offset between the server time and the client time. A function can then return the server time at any stage by using the current client date and applying the server difference.

Here's an example:

```
var serverDate;
var serverOffset;
$.get('server/date/url', function(data){
   // server returns a json object with a date property.
   serverDate = data.date;
   serverOffset = moment(serverDate).diff(new Date());
});

function currentServerDate()
{
    return moment().add('milliseconds', serverOffset);
}
```

Comment: That is what I am doing, but I ned to poll the server to get the date every time. moment.set throws has no method 'set'. moment().set('time') does not work either.

Comment: Answer amended to compute server date offset

Comment: Could use the response header `Date`. Becomes an issue with cross-domain (CORS) and needing to `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` though.

Answer (score 31):

Since Moment.js 2.10.7 it is possible to [change the time source](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/) (see the [PR](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/2766) that has introduced it).

You can use it to synchronize the time Moment.js sees with your server's time.

```
function setMomentOffset(serverTime) {
  var offset = new Date(serverTime).getTime() - Date.now();
  moment.now = function() {
    return offset + Date.now();
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the transit time of getting the serverTime? Won't network delay always make it appear like the server is a few milliseconds behind?  This can be a problem if you are doing date.fromNow(), you might get "in a few seconds" on something that just happened.

Comment: Yes it will, but for my use case of setting the clock to display when the client is a Raspberry Pi that does not have the clock set, this is acceptable. If the dates you are comparing are coming from the same server it probably won't be a problem either. You can add a conditional that checks to make dates before "now" it to say "just now" or something if that is an issue for you.

Comment: @RMK I am using npm library ntp-client to get a hopefully more accurate timestamp as the protocol takes into account the round trip time.

Answer (score 1):

---

title: Changing Time Source
version: 2.11.0
signature: |

### moment.now = function () { return +new Date(); }

If you want to change the time that Moment sees, you can specify a method that
returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970).

The default is:

```
moment.now = function () {
    return +new Date();
}
```

This will be used when calling `moment()`, and the current date used when tokens are omitted from
`format()`. In general, any method that needs the current time uses this under the hood.

[Changing Time Source](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

> var momentFromServer = moment(input);
>
> var clampedMoment = momentFromServer.max();

I've found this is mentioned in momentjs documentation.

*Sometimes, server clocks are not quite in sync with client clocks. This ends up displaying humanized strings such as "in a few seconds" rather than "a few seconds ago". You can prevent that with moment#max():*
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/max/