# how to sync the date with the server time (Moment.js)

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

I have this code an it work like a charm

```
function muestraDias() { 
var day=0; 
var server = TimeSync.serverTime()
var d= new Date();  
var weekdays = new Array(7);
weekdays[0] = "Domingo";
weekdays[1] = "Lunes";
weekdays[2] = "Martes";
weekdays[3] = "Miercoles";
weekdays[4] = "Jueves";
weekdays[5] = "Viernes";
weekdays[6] = "Sabado";
 for (i=1; i<8;i++){  

          document.getElementById("sub"+i).innerHTML = moment(d).locale("es").format('L');
          day=weekdays[d.getDay()];
          document.getElementById("titulo"+i).innerHTML =day;
          d.setDate(d.getDate() +1);
      }
  }
```

But its not quite efficient, for example if the user have the wrong date on the computer, the function will render a different date, and my templates breaks, so i want to pass the  variable  `server`to the current date buts im getting **invalid date**, what im doing wrong here?

for the variable server, im using **mizzao:timesync**.

Also i have this question, supposting i deploy my app on lets say Modulus, the server will get the TimeZone from whatever part of america they have it, so its there a way to setting time zone on server side? something like

```
moment.tz(currentDateVariable, "America/Mexico_city");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moment.js set the base time from the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629561/moment-js-set-the-base-time-from-the-server)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about TimeSync or what that is, but my guess would be that `TimeSync.serverTime()` returns a string containing the servertime.

The code however expects a date-object (on which you can perform `getDate()` to get the date and `getDay()` to get the day).

So what you would have to do in that case is split the server-string into parts (year, month, etc.)
and pass that as parameters to the `Date()` object, like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: `TimeSync.serverTime` returns msec since epoch, so you can convert it to a `Date` with `new Date(TimeSync.serverTime())` or to a `moment` with `moment(TimeSync.serverTime())`.