# How to set a default offset in Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm currently using Moment.js to manipulate dates and times.

I'm trying to avoid problems if the a user is changing manually the time on his device.

So I'm getting the server time, checking the offset with the browser time.

```
var offset = moment(browserTime).diff(moment(serverTime));
```

But I don't want to store that offset and having to apply it each time I'm creating a new moment as:

```
var foo = moment().add('milliseconds', offset);
```

So is there a way to set that offset in Moment so every new moment will have that offset applied? Something like:

```
moment.setOffset(offset);

var foo = moment();
var bar = moment(new Date()).add('milliseconds', offset);

if (foo.isSame(bar)) {
    // success
}
```

If not, it might be a good idea to add that feature to Moment.js (note for me).

Thanks.

P.S.: I know that the question is closely related to [Moment.js set the base time from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629561/moment-js-set-the-base-time-from-the-server) but the proposed answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: So, add a global offset? What happens if moment is used elsewhere on your website and the offset is not needed? Being able to get an alternatively configured instance of moment (or a wrapper around it) would be a better way of doing something like this, IMO; something like, `var myMoment = moment.withConfig({ offset: ... });`.

Comment: What if the offset was stored in moment and then you could call ```moment().applyOffset();``` ? Then no problem for the rest of then moments and you don't have to expose the offset value globaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like:

```
var offsetMoment = (function(){
    var globalOffset = moment.duration(); // Defaults to no offset
    var offsetMoments = []; // Stores all moments that have a global offset
    var throwIfNotOffsetMoment = function(moment){ // Regular moment objects can't use offset methods
        if(! moment.isOffsetMoment){
            throw "- Moment is not an offsetMoment.";
        }
    };

    // Sets an the globalOffset and applies it to all offsetMoments
    // Offset is not relative to the current offset, example:
    //     now.setGlobalOffset(1,'day') //tommorrow
    //     now.setGlobalOffset(-1,'day') //yesterday, not today
    // Same arguments accepted as moment.duration
    moment.fn.setGlobalOffset = function(){
        var offset = moment.duration.apply(this,arguments);
        throwIfNotOffsetMoment(this);
        for(i in offsetMoments){
            offsetMoments[i].subtract(globalOffset).add(offset); // Subtract the old offset and add the new one
        }
        globalOffset = offset;
        return this;
    }

    // Return a new moment object without the offset
    moment.fn.baseTime = function(){ 
        throwIfNotOffsetMoment(this);
        return this.clone().subtract(globalOffset);
    };

    // Return a factory function to offsetMoment that creates offset moments
    // Makes it work exactly like the momentjs's constructor
    return function(){
        offsetMoments.push(moment.apply(this,arguments));
        offsetMoments[offsetMoments.length-1].isOffsetMoment = true;
        offsetMoments[offsetMoments.length-1].add(globalOffset);
        return offsetMoments[offsetMoments.length-1];
    }
})();

// Usage
var offsetA = offsetMoment("2012-10-05");
offsetA.setGlobalOffset(5,'minutes'); // 2012-10-05 00:05
offsetA.baseTime(); // return new moment object = 2012-10-05 00:00

var offsetB = offsetMoment(moment()); // five minutes from now
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/qeemLuso/4/)** with some basic test cases.

It could be done similarly by extending the prototype but this works well enough.

Basically, you are wrapping `moment.js` in `offsetMoment` and giving it some shared variables. And then extending `moment.fn` so that you can access/manipulate the shared variables easily.

It's limited to one global offset (but regular moment still work without offsets).

It doesn't affect moment's regular functionality at all. And `offsetMoment` objects should play well with `moment` objects.

Should be easy enough to tweak it to exact specifications.