# Moment.js fromNow() a few seconds too early

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I'm having an issue using the moment.js "fromNow()" function to format a time with text like "a few seconds ago", "an hour ago" etc.

It's working perfectly apart from the fact it's a few seconds too early, which is almost always unnoticeable but if I create an entry in the DB and immediately refresh my page, it will tell me the entry I'm looking at was created "in a few seconds" (which is obviously impossible).

This is the code I'm using to return the time ago text...

```
moment(create_date_from_mysql_db  + " +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z").fromNow()
```

(where create_date_from_mysql_db will look something like: "2016-02-04 23:05:25")

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?  I took the exact formatting arguments from another stackoverflow post because I was seeing discrepancies between DB and Browser time.  Now I simply need to find a way to fix this final discrepancy of a few seconds - even a hack solution like somehow adding a few seconds to the calculation would be fine by me!  Thanks for any thoughts at all.

Comment: [fromNow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)
As it said - 'in a few seconds' would be shown no more than 45 seconds after record has been added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the database is on a different server this is perfectly possible  - it's a result of one or both machines not synchronising their clocks.  In your case it sounds like the clock on your machine (where the browser's running) is several seconds behind the server.

Perhaps the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629561/moment-js-set-the-base-time-from-the-server) will help.

Comment: Thanks searlea - so since I could have user browsers from all over the world with slightly different system time, there's basically nothing I can do about this?  Or would it make sense to at least add 30 seconds or so onto my calculation so I'm reasonably confident nobody will see something that was created in the future?  (If so, any thoughts on how to achieve that would be really appreciated!)

Comment: p.s. for the benefit of anyone else looking at this post, here's the hack solution...moment(create_date_from_mysql_db  + " +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z").subtract(20,'s').fromNow();