# World Clock not displaying correct time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a digital clock for three different time zones, Los Angeles, Denver, and New York. The issue I am having is that if a user is based in Los Angeles the Denver clock is displaying LA time and not the correct Denver time which also leads me to believe that the NY time may be off as well. Is there a way to adjust my javascript so that the time is not based on a users location but rather the actual time zone for which I am trying to display regardless of where the user may be located?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function timeDisplay() {
var currentTime = new Date();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
//var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var meridiem = " ";

if(hours >= 12){
  hours = hours - 12;
  meridiem = "pm";
}
else{
  meridiem = "am";
}
if(hours === 0){
  hours = 12;
}
if(hours < 10){
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
if(minutes < 10){
  minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

var clockDiv = document.getElementById('denver');
clockDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem;
}

timeDisplay();
setInterval(timeDisplay, 1000);



//function to display time in (EST) New York 
function newYorkTimeDisplay(offset) {
var currentTime = new Date();  
currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours()+offset); 

var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
//var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var meridiem = " ";

if(hours >= 12){
  hours = hours - 12;
  meridiem = "pm";
}
else{
  meridiem = "am";
}
if(hours === 0){
  hours = 12;
}
if(hours < 10){
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
if(minutes < 10){
  minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

var newYorkDiv = document.getElementById('newYork');      
newYorkDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem; 
}

newYorkTimeDisplay(+2);
setInterval(newYorkTimeDisplay, 1000, +2); 

});
```

html

```
<li>
    <span class="updated">
         <span class="stat stat-nyc">
             <span class="stat-content stat-content-nyc"><span id="newYork"></span></span>
         </span>&nbsp;
    </span>
</li>

<li>
    <span class="updated">
         <span class="stat stat-den">
             <span class="stat-content stat-content-den"><span id="denver"></span></span>
         </span>&nbsp;
    </span>
</li>

<li>
    <span class="updated">
         <span class="stat stat-la">
             <span class="stat-content stat-content-la"><span id="losAngeles"></span></span>
         </span>&nbsp;
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: `new Date();`  bases it's time off of the users system clock.  Not a universal time.  If you want it to be consistent you will have to use a library that uses a internet time to get a constant value, such as offered with `moment.js`

Comment: Related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629561/moment-js-set-the-base-time-from-the-server#19629658