# Getting the Date in stencil bigcommerce

Tags: date, bigcommerce

I'm setting up a minimum and maximum number of days a customer can return a product. But my problem is that how can I get the current Date on stencil bigcommerce? I tried using the

```
{{moment "now" "MM/DD/YYYY"}}
```

It works great but the problem is that when I change the current date of my computer the output of the code changes also. That is why I wanted to get like the "Server Date", just to be sure I will always getting the correct current date.

Comment: Are you working locally, or on a live store? We'd expect the time to reflect the date on your computer when working locally, but when you upload the theme, the {{moment}} should be evaluated server side, and return the server time. But let us know if that matches what you're seeing :)

Comment: @Karen White,When I created the logic I use the moment library included in bigcommerce in the JS file, will it be the same as the handlebars? will that use server time when I uploaded the theme? thank you

Comment: Hey @nklenta , to confirm, are you using the {{moment}} Handlebars helper included in Stencil, or are you calling the moment() method in another way?

Comment: @KarenWhite I'm using the moment() inside the JS file and not on the template.

Comment: Thanks for confirming--in that case, you'd want to take an approach more like the solutions suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629561/moment-js-set-the-base-time-from-the-server